# Why is this copy constructor not working?

Tags: c++, class, oop

g++ says there is no match for the call (Order) (Order&), when it comes to a line in the main program which calls order's copy constructor.

Order.h- It contains the class order

```
class Order
{

private:

int orderNo;



public:

Order()
{}

//Copy Constructor
Order(Order &o)
{
    orderNo = o.putOrderNo();
}

Order(int i)
{
    orderNo = i;
}

};
```

the erroring code is in the main file-

```
bool setCurrentOrder(Order o)
{
     CurrentOrder(o);     //currentOrder is a global var defined elsewhere.
                          //after this, there are some comparisons to determine 
                          //whether the object was copied, then true or false is returned.
}
```

The compiler refuses to accept the line "CurrentOrder(o)" which copies details of o into another object of class Order called CurrentOrder.
Do I have to overload the = operator or is there another way to overcome this?

**EDIT**

This code is outdated, I have since fixed this problem and I have also reworked this and other code, so I now have some new ones which I shall ask about soon!

Comment: Please study the posting guidelines, you are supposed to extract a minimal example, format it consistently etc.

Comment: hmm, ok. I will keep that in mind next time. however, here, I felt the source files were small enough, which is why I did this.

Comment: It's not about absolute size but that you focus on the essence of your issue. Many questions are answered that way before they were even asked here.

Comment: Your post is incomplete. I cannot reproduce your error. Please amend or delete (or face being closed)

Comment: @Walter Sorry, I will be refining it further.

Answer (score 9):

A copy **constructor** constructs a new object. Since `CurrentOrder` already exists, it doesn't make sense to construct it again: `CurrentOrder(o)` is meaningless. To **assign** the value of `o` to `CurrentOrder` use assignment: `CurrentOrder = o;`.

Comment: `CurrentOrder(o)` isn't meaningless - it's the call of `operator()` method, which is undefined in given piece of code.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: @Raghav did you implement `operator=`?

Comment: @Raghav - that's has nothing to do with the problem you raised here, which is about modifying one object. Post a new question with compilable code that shows how std's container classes get messed up, including what you did and how you determined that they got messed up.

Comment: @Raghav - given the definition of the class, it's meaningless. If the question had been different, the answer could also be different. But it wasn't, so it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem was solved by just overloading the = operator.

Basically, I wanted to use copy constructors to define how the object would be copied, however, operator overloading was probably the best option under the circumstances, because my intention was to assign the values in the old object to the new one. This has been explained in the other answer by Pete.

here is how it was done-

```
void operator=(Order &o)
{
 orderNo = o.orderNo;
}
```

Thank you for the constructive criticism. I'll keep it in mind when asking more questions.